# Java application log track

Tags: java, swing

If a programmer developed a java application(say swing application) with out any log files(poor coding standards..).At one point of time,the application crashes.

Then how will one track the cause for the crash ?

**Note**: ***faced this scenario question in an Interview.***

I replied like may be he possibly can track from JVM.(not sure...).

Please anyone tell me, how to track the issue?

Comment: Stack traces.  Or logs.  With stack traces in them.  Or emails.  With stack traces in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there has been an exception, generally you can examine the stack trace in the Standard Output (Standard Error), if you are in an IDE in the Console, that is the default target for jvm log. However in the case of "poor coding standards" as you say, the exception could be catched without printing the stack trace nor re-throwing it to upper levels...

Answer (score 0):

Besides looking on the console for the stack trace, another option would be to reproduce it in the development environment and then add logging information or debug it.